# Is a standalone mesh Wi-Fi router (without nodes) any better than a standard Wi-Fi router with the same capacity?

Tags: wifi, router

Is a standalone mesh Wi-Fi router, one without any additional nodes on the network, any better than a standard Wi-Fi router with the same capacity? I need to replace my Wi-Fi router and my home is not big enough to need any nodes to expand coverage but I have the option to buy a mesh Wi-Fi router (without nodes) for a good deal and I wonder if it's worth it.

Comment: You should improve this question. What does "better" mean to you? (# of devices, range, or bandwidth to a single device) Also share the models you are trying to decide between, since there are specifics to every router that can be exceptions to the general advice. For example "More antennas is faster" is generally a true statement, but one router may have 8 antennas where only 2 of them support MIMO. While another router with 6 antennas uses all 6 for MIMO so it gets better performance.